# How to specify yaw in a ROS launch file?

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm having trouble getting my robot to face the right direction when it is spawned in the Gazebo world. Here's what I have in my launch file:

```
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
      args="-urdf -model clearpath_jackal -param robot_description -x 0 -y -10 -z 1.0 -Y 1.5708" />
```

Note that I'm trying to use the -Y argument to specify yaw but when I launch Gazebo the robot is always facing the same way, regardless of what value I specify.

Can anybody make any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25124/how-to-specify-yaw-in-a-ros-launch-file?/) by [Py](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26970/py/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have already tested with Gazebo 9 and ROS Noetic and it's working

[image: image description]

I run this bash script

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4
do
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -urdf -file model.urdf -x $i -y 0 -z 3.0 -reference_frame world -model drone$i -Y $i
done
```

can you provide more details? which Gazebo and ROS version are you using?

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26970/py/) on 2020-05-20**:
Thanks for this. I've played around with your script and it seems to be working fine now with my originally posted launch code.....not sure what happened!